# Producing json in a Scala app using json4s

Tags: json, scala, scalatra, json4s

I am attempting to produce JSON in a Scala app using json4s. Fairly straight forward, Here's some sample value I put together to test it in my Scalatra app:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._


object JsonStub {
    val getPeople = 
        ("people" ->
            ("person_id" -> 5) ~
            ("test_count" -> 5))

}
```

In my controller, I simply have:

```
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.{DefaultFormats, Formats}

class FooController(mongoDb: MongoClient)(implicit val swagger: Swagger) extends ApiStack with NativeJsonSupport with SwaggerSupport {

get ("/people", operation(getPeople)) {
        JsonStub.getPeople
    }   

}
```

The output I'm seeing in the browser however, is the following:

```
{
  "_1": "people",
  "_2": {
    "person_id": 5,
    "test_count": 5
  }
}
```

Any clue where the `_1` and `_2` keys are coming from? I was expecting this output instead:

```
{
  "people":{
    "person_id": 5,
    "test_count": 5
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing in the output is a reflectively serialized tuple, which has fields `_1` and `_2`. This is because the return type that the compiler has inferred for `JsonStub.getPeople` is `Tuple2[String, JObject]`.

The json4s DSL uses implicit conversions to turn values like the tuple into a `JValue`. But, if you don't tell the compiler you wanted a `JValue`, it won't apply the conversion.

Ideally, this would result in a compile error, because you tried to produce JSON from something that isn't the right type. Unfortunately, because your web framework assumes you want to fall back to reflection-based serialization, it means there is another way to turn the tuple into JSON, which isn't what you wanted.

If you explicitly tell the compiler that you want a `JValue` and not a `Tuple2`, the DSL's implicit conversion will be applied in the correct place.

```
val getPeople: JValue = 
    ("people" ->
        ("person_id" -> 5) ~
        ("test_count" -> 5))
```

Comment: That did it Ben, thank you so much. Any tips for how I could have figured this one out without posting here first? :-) There is probably a way to default all of my values to JValue here also, just not entirely sure how.

Comment: My pro tip would be to not use Scalatra, if you want type-safe development. Other than that, it's always a good idea to specify return types for the public members of an API, *especially* when relying on implicits.

Comment: Is there a way to tell json4s to make the conversion explicitly? I'm running into the same thing and I'd rather not have to litter up my model classes with `JValues`.