# Representing a list of JSON tuples as a case class field, with Json4s

Tags: json, scala, json4s

Given the following JSON:

```json
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz":[
        { "qux" : "quux" },
        { "quuux" : "quuuux" }
    ]
}
```

what's the best way to represent it as a Scala case class? Logically it seems as though it should be something like:

```scala
case class Foo(
  foo: String,
  baz: List[(String, String)]
)
```

However, when I try to parse this with Json4s and Jackson, I get:

```
No usable value for baz
No usable value for _1
Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String
org.json4s.package$MappingException: No usable value for baz
No usable value for _1
Did not find value which can be converted into java.lang.String
```

Going the other direction, if I construct my expected `Foo`...

```scala
val foo = Foo(foo = "bar", baz = List(("qux" -> "qux1"), ("qux" -> "qux2")))
```

...and write it as JSON, I don't get my list of tuples, I get:

```json
{
  "foo" : "bar",
  "baz" : [ {
    "_1" : "qux",
    "_2" : "qux1"
  }, {
    "_1" : "qux",
    "_2" : "qux2"
  } ]
}
```

I see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534498/producing-json-in-a-scala-app-using-json4s) that despite Json4s [claims](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) to produce objects from `Tuple2s` in the DSL, it can't actually do it for an object field unless that object field is defined as a `JValue`. Since I want to do other things with my `Foo` model object besides serialize and deserialize it, I don't particularly want to define it in terms of `JValues`.

Given that, what should I be doing, here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two options how to handle this:

1. Use a List of Map
2. Write a custom conversion function between (String, String) and JObject(JField(*, JString(*))

Sometimes it is also useful working directly on the AST or extracting a plain Map[String, Any] via the [values](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/ast/src/main/scala/org/json4s/JsonAST.scala#L91-L98) function. The Tuple2 conversion is valid as long as you are working with the JValue DSL, but not when doing extraction to/decomposition from Scala types.

```scala
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._

val json = """{
             |    "foo": "bar",
             |    "baz":[
             |        { "qux" : "quux" },
             |        { "quuux" : "quuuux" }
             |    ]
             |}""".stripMargin

class StringTupleSerializer extends CustomSerializer[(String, String)](format => ( {
  case JObject(List(JField(k, JString(v)))) => (k, v)
}, {
  case (s: String, t: String) => (s -> t)
}))

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new StringTupleSerializer

case class FooMap(foo: String, baz: List[Map[String, String]])

case class FooTuple(foo: String, baz: List[(String, String)])

val ast = parse(json)

println(ast.extractOpt[FooMap])
//  Some(FooWithMap(bar,List(Map(qux -> quux), Map(quuux -> quuuux))))

println(ast.extractOpt[FooTuple])
//  Some(FooWithTuple(bar,List((qux,quux), (quuux,quuuux))))

val foo1 = FooMap(foo = "bar", baz = List(Map("qux" -> "qux1"), Map("qux" -> "qux2")))
val foo2 = FooTuple(foo = "bar", baz = List(("qux" -> "qux1"), ("qux" -> "qux2")))

println(pretty(Extraction.decompose(foo1)))
println(pretty(Extraction.decompose(foo2)))
```

Comment: Ended up writing a custom serializer. I think this -- "valid as long as you are working with the JValue DSL" -- is the key non-obvious thing, esp. if you're not used to DSL-happy Scala libraries.